# Artisan make:auth login failing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Good day every one, im working with laravel 5.3 trying the make:auth command but it seems that either is broken or im doing something wrong this are the steeps i followed:

1. composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
2. cd blog
3. edit .env to set the database conection
4. artisan make:auth
5. artisan migrate
6. artisan serve
7. register a new user using the generated `/register` page
8. log out
9. try to log in

then i got an `credentials mismatch error` i did this on a new project/Schema on mysql

im using:

- mariaDB 10.1.8-MariaDB
- php 5.6.15
- laravel 5.3
- windows 10 home edition

i started tracing the code but i can find what is causing this error

any idea on how to solve this?

just tested in laravel 5.2 does not present this behavior.
also i tested to use 1 through 6 as a password as suggested in the comments but it failed, im opening a bug report on laravel´s GitHub page and i´ll link to it in the comments

Comment: Did you set database? Inside .env file ?

Comment: yes i did, else i would have an eloquent exception

Comment: Did you try with another new registration ?

Comment: yes i did, new user is logged in right away after sign up but i i log out then i cant login back

Comment: Really strange. I guess there is no auto conversation in login controller. Are you trying with all small case and simple password ?

Comment: Also be sure that you are registeting and login in the same url.

Comment: as password im using 1 through 0 as a password (i know its not a safe password) and im using `artisan serve` as local server, also what do you mean by `auto conversation` i dint find anything, did you mean "conversion", i didnt find where laravel performs the hash comparison but my bet is that the problem is in that part

Comment: Just a suggestion use 123456 as a password  , I guess 011001 is going 11001, auto conversion.

Comment: i tried your sugestion and it also failed, i also tried with Laravel 5.2 and it working, so ill downgrade, anyqwy i opened a issue ticket at https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16393

Comment: i figured it out, my migration has Password (capital P) instead of password, sorry for wsting your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it, my migrations was wrong, it had "Password" (capital P) instead of "password" sorry for wasting your time

Comment: Was it default migration or you made this ?

Comment: i edited the migration to add some columns and at some time i change the "p" to "P" by acident